# Loading an html files to a web view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a table view with a lot of items
when i click on a cell in the table it loads a view with a web view outlet, in the web view in viewdidload i have this line of code to load the html file wich is in the project file

```
NSString *name = pagename.text;
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

the code to push from the selected cell to that web view with is called Test is

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) 
{

    Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];

    NSString *name1 = @"ba";
    [[test pagename] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)name1]];

}

else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
{

    Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];

    NSString *name1 = @"bb";
    [[test pagename] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)name1]];

}

else if (indexPath.row == 2) 
{

    Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];

    NSString *name1 = @"bc";
    [[test pagename] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)name1]];

}
```

the html files are called ba,bb,bc and bd .html

the problem is when i select any cell of the four cells i have in the table it shows the same html file "ba.html"

i tried everything , cleaning the project, deleting the files and copying them back, changed the simulator, restarted the lap and even changed the files names.

any help ?

thanks in advance

update :

This is the hole code

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {

        Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];

        NSString *name1 = @"ba";
        [[test pagename] setText:name1];

    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 1) 
    {

        Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];

        NSString *name1 = @"bb";
        [[test pagename] setText:name1];        
    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 2) 
    {

        Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];

        NSString *name1 = @"bc";
        [[test pagename] setText:name1];
    }

    else if (indexPath.row == 3) 
    {

        Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];

        NSString *name1 = @"bd";
        [[test pagename] setText:name1];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presenting the controller before setting the page.

Make 'name' an NSString instance variable in your webview class. Make it a property (nonatomic,retain) and synthesize it.

Instead of setting the viewcontroller's label, set name. 
Then in viewDidLoad, set the label from name.

Set the label from the name, not the other way around.

In the cell was selected:

```
Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
test.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
NSString *name1 = @"bc";
[test setName:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)name1]];
[self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];
```

In the Web view viewdidload

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    pagename.text = self.name;
    [WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}
```

Comment: Still the same , nothing changed

Comment: I am going to have to know more about the 'pagename' object. What is pagename?

Comment: its an IBOutlet UILabel in Test. and there is a UIWebView also in Test both are nonatomic, retain. setting the pagename from the tableview to ba,bb,bc or bd so when the Test loads it knows wich html file to load in the webview outlet in viewdidload method

Comment: the code wich loads in Test is                 NSString *name = pagename.text;
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

Comment: Try that. Use the string as the ivar you set, not the label.

Comment: sorry did not understood that , can you please explain it more

Comment: error  Property 'name' not found on object of type 'Test *' in the first code line, and error Use of undeclared identifier 'name' and the second code line

Comment: ...add it as an ivar as is explained in my post.

Comment: still the same , i added NSString *name in the Test.h and @property (copy) NSString *name; and in the Test.m i added synthesize name;,, copy pasted ur code , no errors but still loading the same page,, i changed the code to self.name = page name.text and still the same

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *name; And stop setting the string to the label, why do you keep doing that?

Comment: i did what u said exactly, didn't set anything , just copied ur code and still the same

Comment: THANK YOU VERY VERY VERY MUCH it worked fine now, i restarted my lap and everything went just fine , i guess something was wrong in Xcode, again THANK YOU for your help and your time :)

Comment: No problem, glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a breakpoint or a log to see if indexPath.row is always 0?

If this is the case, then maybe your table is created in a way that each element is in its own section. You would then have to use indexPath.section as each object would be row 0 of its own section.

Also, I do not know which type of object is 'pagename' but setters generally retain the parameters, so you do not have to create a copy of name1 in

```
[[test pagename] setText:[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)name1]];
```

Note: this really depends on how the property is declared in the class, but typically, those type of properties are retained.

Comment: my table is created in IB, dragged a table view , linked it to the delegate and called it TableView and linked it to the files owner, i tried the .section == 0 and its the same

Comment: i logged the .row and the .section both are giving the right numbers, 0,1,2,.....